# Rebase local branch after pull from remote

Tags: git, branch, rebase, pull

I have a situation as the following where I have 2 local branches - one follows the other which follows the remote branch:
`A(origin/master)---B---C(topic)---D---E---F(master)`

The *topic* branch follows *origin/master* branch.
*Master* branch follows *topic* branch.

After some time the *origin/master* grows and we get the following:

```
A---G(origin/master)
 \
  \
    B---C(topic)---D---E---F(master)
```

So today, in order to rebase I'm doing the following:

```
(topic): git pull --rebase
(topic): git checkout master
(master): git pull --rebase
(master): git checkout topic
(topic):
```

I have this issue with several local branches (several *topics*) and I wonder if there is some command that does all this rebasing for me without the need to checkout between branches.
Does Such functionality exists?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
git fetch
```

first, to update all your `origin/*` names after getting all new commits.  Then use:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

to rebase your own personal, un-pushed `topic` branch to the updated `origin/master`.

(If you're annoyed that your own `master` gets behind, consider simply *deleting* your `master` branch.  You can use the name `origin/master` to find *their* latest `master` any time you need to, and now that you do not have a `master` of your own, you won't feel the urge to update it.)

#### Important notes

If you *have* created a `topic` over on `origin` already, so that `origin/topic` exists, that this won't update your own `origin/topic`—well, unless someone *else* has done something on the Git over at `origin`.  Then it *will* update your `origin/topic`, and then you'd best figure out what that someone-else did.

After running `git rebase origin/master` while on your own `topic`, you can use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` to send the rebased commits and update `topic` on the Git over at origin.  If someone else is using the `topic` there, perhaps via some third Git's `origin/topic`, you may mess with them, just as they might have messed with you above.

Hence, if you *have* pushed `origin/topic`, make sure that everyone *else* agrees that it's OK for your to rebase your own `topic` and to `git push --force` (preferably `-with-lease`).

(One common workflow is to use a third-party server like GitHub to store copies in case private Git repositories are on computers that crash or otherwise lose data.  In this case, you may wish to push in-progress work: if everyone gets *their own* branch names here, and nobody uses anyone else's branches, this "get permission to update a shared branch" problem goes away, because these branches aren't shared, even though everyone can see everyone else's.)